# How to exchange data between Python and C++

Tags: python, c++

I want to write a program in Python that reads 2 numbers (either from a text file or from user input) call a C++ function that takes 2 arguments (the 2 numbers) adds them and returns the result to the Python program. I've already managed to do this using a text file (saving the numbers from python there and then calling the file in the C++ program). But I want to do it directly instead of having to use a text file as a medium. I want to be able to call the function and send it the arguments directly rather than having it to read them from a text file and I would like to have the output returned to the original python code.

Any ideas as to how to proceed as I am fairly new in this area?

Comment: You can use a pipe to communicate with the external program.

Comment: Python [documents how to do this](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Comment: SWIG (http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) makes it easy interfacing C/C++ code to Python.

Comment: So what is the difference in using SWIG, or a python wrapper or sockets/pipes etc?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two different programs, you need to use technologies for [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (pipes, sockets, signals, etc.).

If you want integrate C++ code to a python program, you may use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/) or [this document](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Answer (score 1):

A very powerful tool for integrating Python and C++ is called [sip](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) and it's the tool which the Qt binding PyQt is based on.

You can call functions and even map C++ classes to Python directly (including support for deriving in Python a C++ class).

Answer (score 1):

[Cython](http://cython.org/) supports C++ since version 0.13.

Some reading material:

- [Using C++ in Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html)
- [Wrapping C++ classes with Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/WrappingCPlusPlus)
- [Self-contained example](https://github.com/sturlamolden/cython-cpp-test) (probably very close to what you're trying to achieve)